# Dell Vostro 1200 で　VT-Xを有効にする方法を教えてください。

Tags: virtualbox

Dell Vostor 1200を入手したので遊んでみようと思い、Linuxbeanを入れてその後にVirtualBoxをインストールし、そこにWindows7を入れようとしましたが、以下のようなエラーがでてしまいました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力] 

Virtual Checkerを使ってみると確かに以下のようにVT-xは対応しておりませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

でもCPU-Zを使って、CPUの情報を見るとVT-xは対応しているようです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]  
もう少し調べてみるとMS-DOS起動用のUSBメモリを作って、そこにsymcmosを入れて以下を実行すればよいという記事を見つけました。

1. SYMCMOS.EXE -V2 -lCMOS.TXT
2. CMOS.txtのうちVT-x関係するところを有効にし、BOIS.txtを作成
3. SYMCMOS.EXE -V2 -uBIOS.txt

[教えてほしいこと]  
1. SYMCMOS.EXE -V2 -lCMOS.TXTとやっても以下のようなエラーがでてCMOS.TXTができません。　　対処方法を教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2. CMOS.txtのうちVT-x関係するところというのがパソコンによって、異なるとネットで見つけましたが、
   　Vostro 1200ではどの部分を0001にすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: もし可能でしたらBIOSの画面も載せていただくことはできますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3100さんありがとうございます！！  
わざわざBIOSでできない版もご回答いただき大変感謝いたします。  
早速、CCTKをダウンロードして実験してみましたが、以下のような状態です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`cctk.exe --option`
で見てみると--virtualization自身が対応していないようです。  
CCTKのバージョンはver2.2.1です。Vostro 1200は対応していないのですかね。。。。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: CCTKの最新版はVersion 3.0.0.1, A01みたいですが、そちらは利用できませんでしたか？http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=X0TCK

Answer (score 2):

DELLのマシンでBIOSから設定ができる機種とそうでない機種があるようです。まず、BIOSから設定できる機種の場合です。
(質問に貼られているエラーダイアログ画像でも、BIOSで使用しない設定になっている旨表示されています)

**以下の手順は機種によって異なるかもしれません。項目名が見つからなくてもCPU関連の項目を探してみてください。**

1. マシンを再起動し、ブートメニューが表示されたら`enter bios`に対応するキー(`F2`？)を押します。
2. `BIOS Setup`と出たら`Enter`キーを押します。
3. `Virtualization Support`から`Virtualization`の項目を選択します。
4. `Enable Intel Virtualization Technology`にチェックを入れます。
5. `Apply`し、`Exit`します。
6. 一旦電源を落とし、そこから起動します。VT-xが有効になっていることを確認します。

---

質問者さんの場合、BIOSから設定できない機種のようです。（DELLのノートPCはBIOSに制限があるという記事をいくつか見ましたが、実機がないので、そういう可能性のみ付記しておきます）

以降、実際に試したわけではありませんが`CCTK`というDELLの公式ツールを使うと、VT-xの設定が可能になるようです。若干ややこしいのですが、この`CCTK`、現在は`Dell Command`というものに統合され、その中の`Configure`という名前になっています。

以下より、Windows各種およびRHEL向けのバイナリがダウンロード可能です。

[Dell Command | Configure - Enterprise Client - Wiki - Client and Mobile Solutions - Dell Community](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/7532.dell-command-configure)

仮想化についてはLinuxの場合

```
$ cctk --virtualization=enable
```

で有効になります。(`windows`の場合は`cctk.exe`に対して同様のオプションを指定）

cf. [Dell Command - Configure Version 3.0 Command Line Interface Reference Guide](http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals/us/en/19/Topic/dell-cmnd-config-v3.0/Dell_Command_Configure_CLI-v3/en-us/GUID-A672047E-5890-4BEE-8C0B-F5449882A869)

尚、`CCTK`関連のドキュメントは以下にあり、インストールガイドやコマンドリファレンスなども用意されています(英語)

[Product Support - Dell US](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-cmnd-config-v3.0/manuals)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。F2でBIOS画面がでますが、Virtualization supportがないので困っている次第です。

Comment: すみません。BIOSで変更できない機種について追記しました。

Comment: 出荷時期によってもBIOSが異なる可能性があるのと、上に書いたBIOSの手順が汎用的では無さそうなので、注意書きを追加しました。

Answer (score 1):

3100さん何度もご回答ありがとうございます。Version 3.0.0.1, A01も試してみたのですが、  
以下のように--virtualizationaがない状況です。
さすがにもうあきらめるしかないのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 推測でお手数をおかけして申し訳ありません。公式フォーラムにもVostro 1200の同じCPUについて古い質問がありました。それによると、不可能な可能性は高そうです。[Enable Hardware Assisted Virtualization in Vostro 1200 - Microsoft OS Forum - Software & Operating Systems - Dell Community](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19323827)

尚、作業によって状況が更新されている場合は、回答として作成する代わりに、単に一番上の質問文を更新して情報を追加されるほうが良いかもしれません。

Comment: ダメそうですね。アドバイスありがとうございます。質問文を修正するようにします。